# How long is the time allowed between exit and re entry from the U.S on an esta visa?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I have a valid two year Established Visa,and I would like to exit the U.S for a month, and then return after one month,  but i was told i needed three months between exit and re entry. Can someone clarify? I am from Australia.

Comment: Not worth a full answer, but if this were true I'd have been screwed, since I needed the esta when I just passed through the US to get to Colombia, and flew back the same way a month later. But can't be sure my situation is exactly the same of course.

Comment: No such thing as an ESTA Visa. ESTA is documentation you need for the visa waiver. However if you have  a 2 year visa, shouldn't you be entering/leaving on that and not the VWP which only allows you to remain for 90 days?